# Unixtimestamp time difference in SQL Query

Tags: time, unix-timestamp, difference

I want to get time difference with `UNIXTIMESTAMP`in `SQL`. I want to retrieve data from database that queries inserted reports like week, month. I am inserting with `UNIXTIMESTAMP`. So I want to get the difference between `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and query inserted date.

Comment: Any particular RDBMS?

Answer (score 0):

you would need to convert the UNIXTIMESTAMP to date time format before you can find the difference. here is a post from oracle community to convert UNIXTIMESTAMP to date time value

https://community.oracle.com/thread/302756?start=0&tstart=0